# Concatenate many rows into a single text string works wrong when saved as view

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is wrong in my query:

```
Select distinct 
 c2.Id AS ClientId, 
 c2.Name AS ClientName,
 substring(
    (
    Select ',' + cast(bq1.Id as nvarchar)  AS [text()]
    From dbo.BatchQuote bq1 INNER JOIN
    dbo.ProjectBatch AS pb1 ON pb1.Id = bq1.ProjectBatchId INNER JOIN
    dbo.Project AS p1 ON p1.Id = pb1.ProjectId INNER JOIN
    dbo.Client AS c1 on c1.Id = p1.ClientId
    Where c1.Id = c2.Id
    For XML PATH ('')
    ),
    2, 100000) [BatchQuoteIds]
FROM dbo.Client AS c2 INNER JOIN
     dbo.Project AS p2 ON p2.ClientId = c2.Id INNER JOIN
     dbo.ProjectBatch AS pb2 ON pb2.ProjectId = p2.Id INNER JOIN
     dbo.BatchQuote AS bq2 ON bq2.ProjectBatchId = pb2.Id
WHERE
(bq2.BatchQuoteStatusId = 4)
```

entered in SSMS work fine and gives correct results.
but when I am trying to save it as View (I need to have view returning this results) SSMS throws me below error:

```
Error in WHERE clause near '('.
Error in WHERE clause near 'BatchQuoteIds'.
Unable to parse query text.
```

and when executing this View got wrong results (ClientNames are correct, but BatchQuoteIds are wrong)

thanks in advance

Comment: in order to test,you can remove distinct and comment inner query i.e. [BatchQuoteIds] part.see what happen.analyse the result.There is no reason that view is not compiling now.only concern is whether query giving you correct data.

Comment: Please post the view definition. If there was any error with the statement it wouldn't work in SSMS either. Moreover, a view that can't be created, can't be queried. Where did you get the wrong results from? Are you querying a previous version of the view?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove `()` from `WHERE` clause? Really you don't need to use `()`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 c2.Id AS ClientId, 
 c2.Name AS ClientName,
 SUBSTRING(
    (
    SELECT ',' + CAST(bq1.Id AS NVARCHAR)  AS [text()]
    FROM dbo.BatchQuote bq1 INNER JOIN
    dbo.ProjectBatch AS pb1 ON pb1.Id = bq1.ProjectBatchId INNER JOIN
    dbo.Project AS p1 ON p1.Id = pb1.ProjectId INNER JOIN
    dbo.Client AS c1 ON c1.Id = p1.ClientId
    WHERE c1.Id = c2.Id
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ),
    2, 100000) [BatchQuoteIds]
FROM dbo.Client AS c2 INNER JOIN
     dbo.Project AS p2 ON p2.ClientId = c2.Id INNER JOIN
     dbo.ProjectBatch AS pb2 ON pb2.ProjectId = p2.Id INNER JOIN
     dbo.BatchQuote AS bq2 ON bq2.ProjectBatchId = pb2.Id
WHERE
bq2.BatchQuoteStatusId = 4
```

Comment: thank you for your response - I tried your suggestion, but got the same error. Of course - you are right - I don't need brackets there.

Answer (score 0):

I made two changes,use stuff instead of substring

```
       Select  
 c2.Id AS ClientId, 
 c2.Name AS ClientName,
 stuff(
    (
    Select ',' + cast(bq1.Id as nvarchar) 
    From dbo.BatchQuote bq1 INNER JOIN
    dbo.ProjectBatch AS pb1 ON pb1.Id = bq1.ProjectBatchId INNER JOIN
    dbo.Project AS p1 ON p1.Id = pb1.ProjectId INNER JOIN
    dbo.Client AS c1 on c1.Id = p1.ClientId
    Where c1.Id = c2.Id
    For XML PATH ('')
    ),
    1, 1,'') [BatchQuoteIds]
FROM dbo.Client AS c2 INNER JOIN
     dbo.Project AS p2 ON p2.ClientId = c2.Id INNER JOIN
     dbo.ProjectBatch AS pb2 ON pb2.ProjectId = p2.Id INNER JOIN
     dbo.BatchQuote AS bq2 ON bq2.ProjectBatchId = pb2.Id
WHERE
(bq2.BatchQuoteStatusId = 4)
```

Comment: thank you for your response, when I try to save it get "The stuff function required 4 arguments(s)"

Comment: check my latest change.

Comment: now it throws errors mentioned in my question. When run displays not groupped data (I need "groupped" by ClientId and ClientName - as in my base query)